# How do I get the Apple Music app to just play one song at a time, and not automatically go to the next song?

Tags: ios, music.app

How do I get the Apple Music app to just play one song and stop, without automatically going to the next song?

Answer (score 1):

It appears the only way to play a single song is for it to be at the end of (or the only item on) a playlist when it's started. Otherwise, Music uses the current context to decide what to play next automatically, such as the rest of an album, song list, or playlist.